# How to perform pagination with the Litho framework?

Tags: android, retrofit2, litho

I am implementing a Retrofit APi for getting data from the server and showing this in a `RecyclerView` using the Litho framework, and it's doing well. As all of us know when we have infinite data to show in recyclerview we have to implement the pagination pattern. And I know this, but I am confused how to implement this in the Litho framework. Litho the provides `onScrollListener()` method:

```java
final Component component = Recycler.create(context)
    .binder(recyclerBinder)
    .onScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            //
        })
    .build();
```

I don't know: how to use a customized `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener` for endless scrolling in Litho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success implementing the "infinite" scroll pattern leveraging the `recyclerBinder` within the `onScrolled` method of a `OnScrollListener`. A trivial example would be the following:

```
//Initialize the RecyclerBinder
recyclerBinder = new RecyclerBinder(c, new LinearLayoutInfo(getContext(), OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false));

//Initialize a recycler component
Component component = Recycler.create(c)
                .onScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        // use the recyclerBinder to determine what items at what position are visible - 
                        // (you could also use the findLastVisibleItemPosition() method depending on your implementation)
                        int firstVisibleItemPosition = recyclerBinder.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                        //check if it is within range relative to the current available items and is not loading (room to improve/modify logic pending use case)
                        if((recyclerBinder.getItemCount() - 5) <= firstVisibleItemPosition && !isLoading) {
                            //if so - use your service to get the next page
                            service.getNextPage();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

Then in a call back method - you can insert your items starting at the item count

```
public void callback(List<T> results) {
    int position = recyclerBinder.getItemCount();
    for(T result: results) {
        Component component = //assemble your component(s) ...
        ComponentInfo.Builder info = ComponentInfo.create().component(component);
        recyclerBinder.insertItemAt(position, info.build());
        position++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, in  `onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)` method  you call `service.getNextPage();` i didn't understand , Is `getNextPage()` is customized method ?

Comment: @HussainKhan - yes - this is where you need to make a call to fetch the next page of data, perhaps a call to your retrofit service incrementing the page number your API should fetch from.